# WPF How to bind a control which is defined in a style from the element which uses the style?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm new to wpf and xaml,
trying to understand the basic concepts by writing a simple app using MVVM.

One thing I can't wrap my head around is

**How to bind a control eg. textBox which is defined in a style to a viewModel from the control which uses this style?**

Style Example (I like to bind the textBox named "SearchBox"):

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"
       x:Key="FlatSearchBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Border CornerRadius="10"
                        Background="#353340"
                        Width="200" Height="40">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle StrokeThickness="1"/>
                        <TextBox Margin="1"
                                 Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                                 BorderThickness="0"
                                 Background="Transparent"
                                 VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                 Padding="5"
                                 Foreground="#CFCFCF"
                                 x:Name="SearchBox"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                   IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                   Text="Search"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                   Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                   FontSize="11"
                                   Foreground="DarkGray">
                            <TextBlock.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=SearchBox}" Value="">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBlock.Style>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Part of XAML in which the style is applied to a textBox:

```
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                              FontSize="20"
                              Style="{StaticResource FlatSearchBox}"
                              Text="{Binding CurrentFinanceModel.Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource currencyConverter}}"/>
```

The text binding should apply to the textBox named "SearchBox" in the style.

Hope the question is clear and I did not make a mistake, because it's my first question here :)
Thanks!

Comment: Control in style already has the same `DataContext`, so just do bind like you did it for a `TextBox` the style was applied to.

Comment: Hm, so should I bind to the viewModel within the style? Then the style can't be used on different controls. I thought the style is used to be reusable.

Comment: You binded in Style first then You bind again in defining the textbox control Text="Binding CurrentFinanceModel.Value

Comment: I think you should bind only in textbox control instead of style. Hope It will work :)

Comment: Please show me ViewModel and your xaml.cs file too

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can Upload the other code later. But there shoul be no problem. Without the style the binding of the textbox works. And if I apply this "Binding CurrentFinanceModel.Value" directly to the textbox in style it also works.